# Providing a LIMIT param in Django query without taking a slice of a QuerySet

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I have a utility function in my program for searching for entities. It takes a `max_count` parameter. It returns a QuerySet.

I would like this function to limit the max number of entries. The standard way would be to take a slice out of my QuerySet:

```
return results[:max_count]
```

My problem is that the views which utilize this function sort in various ways by using `.order_by()`. This causes exceptions as re-ordering is not allowed after taking a slice.

Is it possible to force a "LIMIT 1000" into my SQL query without taking a slice?

Comment: afaik [:max_count] is in query evalualed as LIMIT. If you use order_by, then it makes sense you are not allowed to re-order result, because you got only subset of all records and next query with order_by performed on subset can return different result.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I understand that. My question is if there is another way of doing a LIMIT which will not take a slice and allow resorting later in the execution.

Comment: @KoliberServices I had the same question and actually dug around, and it turns out its easy to do! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360146/limiting-the-number-of-results-from-a-django-queryset-without-using-slice/29360314#29360314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `results[:max_count]` in a view, after `.order_by()`. Don't be afraid of requesting too much from DB, query won't be evaluated until the slice (and even after it either).

Comment: Nice, but you still get a ` Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.` using that approach. its really bad that django doesn't provide a way to limit queries other than slicing that breaks stuff

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass QuerySet to achieve this, by simply ignore every slice and do [:max_count] at last in __getitem__, but I don't think it worths with the complex and side-effects.

If you are worrying about memory consumption by large queryset, follow http://www.mellowmorning.com/2010/03/03/django-query-set-iterator-for-really-large-querysets/

For normal usage, please just follow DrTyrsa's suggestion. You could write shortcuts to shorten the order_by and afterwards slice in code to simplify your code.