# Limiting the number of results from a Django QuerySet, without using slice

Tags: python, django

The way to limit the returned set of results from a Django queryset is done via an array slice. For example, to get the first 5 people:

```
People.objects.all()[0:5]
```

Or, to get them ordered by name:

```
People.objects.order_by(name)[0:5]
```

Or ordered by name, but only those over 65:

```
People.objects.order_by(name).filter(age__gt=65)[0:5]
```

In fact the *only* activity I can think of on a query set that *doesn't* have a function is limiting.

**What I'd like to know is, it there a method (internal, documented or otherwise) that can be called on a `QuerySet` that acts as a limit or slice?
If not, what is the best way about doing this?**

---

Notes:

- <sub>Yes, this is probably a bad idea, no I'm not super keen on implementing it, but if there were a *good* reason for it to be done, could it be?</sub>
- <sub>Yes, I'm aware slices are executed lazily, that's not what I'm asking.</sub>
- <sub>[This is not a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836659/providing-a-limit-param-in-django-query-without-taking-a-slice-of-a-queryset), as the accepted answer says:</sub>

  > <sub>Do `results[:max_count]` in a view, after `.order_by()`.</sub>

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish or avoid by not using a slice?

Comment: Nothing really. I was looking at some code for a django library that could only return a list, not a queryset, and there was an issue around slicing it, because the lazy aspect of slicing wasn't relevant as it converted the whole queryset to a list first.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets), slicing is the only way to do this.

Comment: Seems to me like you'd have to thread any such call into the third party library - the problem isn't with the syntax, it's with evaluating the qs before you want it to.

Comment: @thefourtheye because the slicing is lazy it actually done until the last possible moment. I dug in the code after the comments, and it seems you can just call the internal limiting method very easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewing the code of [Django Querysets, its not as blackboxy](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L268) as it seemed

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    """
    Retrieves an item or slice from the set of results.
    """

    # ... trimmed ...

    if isinstance(k, slice):
        qs = self._clone()
        if k.start is not None:
            start = int(k.start)
        else:
            start = None
        if k.stop is not None:
            stop = int(k.stop)
        else:
            stop = None
        qs.query.set_limits(start, stop)
        return list(qs)[::k.step] if k.step else qs

    qs = self._clone()
    qs.query.set_limits(k, k + 1)
    return list(qs)[0]
```

The key line is here:

```
qs.query.set_limits(start, stop)
```

The reason the slice is lazy is because it just takes the `start` and `stop` values and passes them to another method.

[Which corresponds to a call to the sql.Query object here:](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1508)

```
def set_limits(self, low=None, high=None):
```

So it is possible (although probably not recommended) to slice a Queryset like so:

```
people = People.objects.order_by(name).filter(age__gt=65) # unevaluated
people.query.set_limits(start, stop)  # still unevaluated
for person in people:  # now its evaluated
    person.do_the_thing()
```

Comment: I'm still not seeing any point to this - if you can get at the queryset to call `set_limits` on it you can also slice it, and all the limitations on what you can do to a queryset after slicing it will also apply after calling `set_limits`. Maybe if you're looking into the implementation of querysets for research purposes?

Comment: It was very much an academic question. I was mostly curious if it could be done.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Sometimes you want to limit what's returned in the query but still be able to pass a queryset instance around that can be further filtered or manipulated. Using slice results in `Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.`

Comment: @Matt - so will using `set_limits`! All those error checks are done using the `is_sliced` property, which checks for the same values `set_limits` mutates. https://github.com/django/django/blob/adfbf653dc1c1d0e0dacc4ed46602d22ba28b004/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1800 - `set_limits` is just above that code, conveniently.